# multiple insert from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which will return some ids.

```
SELECT ID FROM xf_menu WHERE m.modul_id = 13;
```

Then there is a simple insert query

```
INSERT INTO xp_uziv_menu (menu_id, modul_id, right)  VALUES (???, 136, 3);
```

the values 136 and 3 are constants.

I'm wondering if is it possilbe to write a query where the ids would be passed from the first query to the insert query and executed.

I tried this syntax but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO 
     xp_uziv_menu (menu_id, modul_id, right)  
VALUES 
     (SELECT ID FROM xf_menu WHERE m.modul_id = 13, 136, 3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO xp_uziv_menu (menu_id, modul_id, right)   
SELECT 
    ID,
    136,
    3 
FROM xf_menu WHERE m.modul_id = 13;
```

Comment: I think 136 and 3 are the modul_id and right, not others ID's

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
INSERT INTO xp_uziv_menu (menu_id, modul_id, right)  
SELECT ID, 136, 3 FROM xf_menu WHERE m.modul_id = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
INSERT INTO xp_uziv_menu
 SELECT ID, modul_id, 3 Where id = 13
```